# E45 'Readonly' option is set, vi won't save file changes even with sudo

Tags: permissions, sudo, vi

I am the only user on my laptop. I want to do some changes on readonly .conf file for netbeans and after hit ESC and try to save I get this error E45 'Readonly' option is set. Even though I opened the file using sudo and provided my password. What am I missing?

Comment: "It wont work when using sudo, even with :w! any idea?" this is the last comment on that answer. Any idea?

Comment: Is the target filesystem itself mounted readonly? in a terminal (or using vi shell escape) use the command `findmnt -T path/to/file`

Comment: Yes it is mounted as readonly

Comment: no user will be able to write to a readonly filesystem